# Can swap be encrypted per user?

Tags: security, encryption, swap, multiuser

The problem arises for a multiuser computer with encrypted swap, as to how to allow each user to hibernate and resume from hibernation without compromising the security of the other users.

I'm looking for a way in which each user's swap usage is encrypted specifically for them, such that when they want to resume from hibernation they can do so by entering only *their* password/passphrase. They should not be able to decrypt other users' swap; all users' processes must be stopped until the respective user can provide their passphrase to decrypt their swap and continue their processes.

Users may wish for some or all of their processes to be unencrypted so that they can continue regardless of who resumes the computer.

As long as no personal data is stored in system processes and the system doesn't let users' keys hit swap, then the system's swap doesn't need to be encrypted, and that means that any user can resume the system without compromising other users.

Note that this could be complemented by encrypting the system with a key stored in BIOS firmware such as Coreboot or LibreBoot to make tampering very difficult, but this is a fundamentally different approach based on the apparent difficulty of tampering with the hardware involved rather than a complete cryptographic approach to preventing people from reading personal data of others assuming tampering is not an issue. For optimal security, these two mechanisms could be used together, but in this question, I'm asking for the fully cryptographic approach.

In theory it makes sense, but in practice it may not be implemented. I hope that this is possible in Linux.

Comment: Can these other users gain root access to this host? If they can't, then I think I'm right to say the normal permissions system should prevent them reading the swap files of other users (i.e i think its correct that even on un-encrypted swap, users shouldn't be able to read each others swap files). If they can get root they could probably extract the keys for another users encrypted swap partition anyway?

Comment: If the users do have root access to the computer (and effectively they do if they have direct access to the whole computer, which is implied by the fact they can suspend it in the first place!), then no amount of encryption and fancy footwork with different swap partitions for each user will actually protect the users from each other.  Use different hardware for each user!

Comment: There might be a way to hack together something like this by keeping each user's login session in an LXC container, with their own systemd instances, and swap space stored within private chroots, but I can't offer a concrete suggestion as to how, precisely, that would be implemented.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, anything is possible via software.  You'd have to modify probably some significant portions of the kernel to do this.  If you are talking about now....no.  In fact you cannot allocate system swap space based on a given user at all.

Another avenue of approach is not to allocate any swap space on on physical partition and carve out a large preallocated file for a truecrypt volume, mount it, and create a swapfile under that.  Then set the system to use that file under the truecrypt volume as a swap file.  I do not guarantee the stability nor to processing efficiency of such a move however, this would be to you to experiment with. However, this would be per SYSTEM not per user.

Comment: I'd discourage using TrueCrypt, there are Linux specific solutions for block encryption that should be favored (dm-crypt/LUKS et al).